# what are the main differences between CMD and Powershell?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am looking to start some basic scripting skills for a personal project using Windows 10 but wanted to know the main differences between [CMD](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) and [Powershell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/overview?view=powershell-7)?

Is one or the other more limited in what they can accomplish?

Comment: Either of these would be among the last things on earth I'd use to "start some basic programming skills" - If young and starting from scratch see kodu, scratch, alice3. If more serious try python, I'd also look at [Go](https://golang.org/) and similar (Rust maybe). If you want a programming job you should probably learn C, C++ and Java.

Comment: Programming and scripting to two different things. They can collide based on your goals. Meaning, you can included scripts efforts in your programming. If you want to learn to program, then take a programming course. There are lots of free videos on Youtube to get you there. If you are just interested in scripting languages like CMD, VBScript, Powershell, Python, Perl, et all, for normal systme admin stuff, then Youtube is your friend as well. Just search 'Beginning Programming' and 'Beginning PowerShell' or 'Batch scripting' for cmd stuff, or VBScript.

Comment: Hot take: Learn [Python](https://www.python.org/). PowerShell is great compared to CMD (which is just generally inflexible and difficult to use), but it is still weird and limited in some ways. That is, a lot of the most useful commandlet tools are geared towards very specific, Windows-system oriented goals (e.g. offering very specific types of output), rather than more general scripting. Python bridges the gap nicely. You may have a bit more work setting it up to interact with the OS or getting it to do what you want, but it's fairly simple and powerful and can generally be extended easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CMD is the command shell of windows from Windows NT, before WinNT in Windows 9x/ME era MS-DOS shell "command.com" existed, and that was tightly integrated with MS-DOS. CMD is string based, everything is string there (input and output), just like Bash. And it has some internal commands and also it can execute external command. It is helpful in general troubleshooting purposes.

Powershell was first released in 2005 named Monad. Powershell is a .NET based, object-oriented, cross-platform and open source (In 2016) and a modern shell. Powershell currently has replaced CMD as the default command shell. It has powerful internal commands, which are known as Command-Lets, in short CMDLets. It has direct integration with .NET and COM objects, C#, Windows Forms, Windows Presentation Framework, Active Directory, VB.NET, Windows API, Azure, Office 365, SharePoint online and many more, which has also minimized the need of Windows Script Host and VBScript. Everything including input/output is collection of NET objects in powershell, unlike the other shells. It supports advanced programming features, like better error handling, regular expressions, Foreach loops and more which Batch does not support. It has importable modules, which contain many cmdlets which do same sorts of work.

So:

- CMD is an old text-based command shell, which is technically a programming language but doesn't have that better features, but Powershell is object-oriented and modern shell, and has advanced features like modern high-level programming languages
- Powershell is tightly integrated with different aspects of Windows, and it has been also released for Linux and it is open-source, where CMD is proprietary and only usable in Windows NT (In non-NT versions, you need to use command.com)
- Powershell is much more powerful than CMD/Batch in its power and extent of capability.

So, my opinion is You should use Powershell instead of Batch nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

## Command Prompt and a previous era of computing

Command Prompt used to be the first thing you would see when booting up your computer back in the days of MS-DOS and Windows 3.1. It is still a part of windows as a testament to the many years of backwards compatibility enjoyed by the users of Windows operating systems. Command Prompt is still used by many applications, installers, and power users to modify systems, run batch scripts, and get system information.

## Powershell: A next generation tool for System Administrators

> Windows PowerShell is a command shell and scripting language designed for system administration tasks.  It was built on top of the .NET framework, which is a platform for software programming developed by Microsoft in 2002.<sup>[[1]](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/03/29/windows-powershell-vs-command-prompt-cmd-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-choose/)</sup>

> PowerShell commands, or cmdlets, help you manage your Windows infrastructure. In addition, they enable a user to access the registry, the file system and Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) space on systems remotely. Moreover, the PowerShell command shell enables you to create complex scripts with multiple conditions.<sup>[[1]](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/03/29/windows-powershell-vs-command-prompt-cmd-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-choose/)</sup>

> PowerShell uses cmdlets, which are self-contained programming objects that expose the underlying administration options inside of Windows. Before PowerShell, sysadmins navigated the GUI to find these options, and there was no way to reuse the workflow of clicking through the menus to change options on a large scale.<sup>[[2]](https://www.varonis.com/blog/powershell-vs-cmd/)</sup>

## Main Differences

> [Cmd] is a very old tool that was never intended for remote system administration. Extending its functionality requires additional utilities, such as Microsoft Sysinternals PsExec.<sup>[[1]](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/03/29/windows-powershell-vs-command-prompt-cmd-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-choose/)</sup>

> PowerShell, on the other hand, provides many cmdlets to simplify system administration tasks. It supports the automation of a wide range of tasks, such as Active Directory administration, user and permissions management, and extracting data about security configurations. Moreover, PowerShell now supports Linux.<sup>[[1]](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/03/29/windows-powershell-vs-command-prompt-cmd-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-choose/)</sup>

> The following table summarizes the key differences between Command Prompt and PowerShell from a programming and operations perspective:<sup>[[1]](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/03/29/windows-powershell-vs-command-prompt-cmd-whats-the-difference-and-which-to-choose/)</sup>

[image]